# Why is snap.data().id not defined?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I can't seem to get the id of the document I'm trying to retrieve.

I have looked at a lot of examples on the web and they all seem to be doing exactly what i'm doing.

```
exports.moveToProfile = functions.firestore
  .document("tempProfiles/{id}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const id = snap.data().id;
    const displayName = snap.data().displayName;

    const profile = await db
      .collection("profiles")
      .doc(id)
      .set({
        displayName: displayName,
        points: 0
      });

    return profile;
  });
```

Comment: i believe you get the doc id by just data.id, not data().id

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `data` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) type object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, the ID of the document represented by that object is its [id property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id).  data() gives you all of its fields (and the formal doucment ID is not one of them, unless you wrote it as a field.)  So, you can get the ID with `data.id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wildcards and parameters then you can use `context.params`.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters .

> ```
>     // Listen for changes in all documents in the 'users' collection
>     exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
>         .document('users/{userId}')
>         .onWrite((change, context) => {
>             // If we set `/users/marie` to {name: "Marie"} then
>             // context.params.userId == "marie"
>             // ... and ...
>             // change.after.denter code hereata() == {name: "Marie"}
>         });
> ```